# Shrinkwrapping after final calculated position, not initial calculated position

Tags: css, css-position

I've got a shrinkwrapping element bounding a series of rows.  Every other row is position:relative and left:40px, so of course it goes outside the shrinkwrapping element on the right. Is there a way to get a shrinkwrapping element to calculate it's width and height *after* the final positions are calculated, instead of based on the initial positions of elements in the flow?  I'm using float:left, tried it in display:table, and display:inline is just a mess and doesn't even shrinkwrap at all.

I could fix it in javascript but I was wondering if there is a CSS way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to calculate the shrink-to-fit width after taking into account the offset of the contents, because [relative positioning](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#relative-positioning) works like this:

> Once a box has been laid out according to the normal flow or floated,
>   it may be shifted relative to this position. This is called *relative
>   positioning*. Offsetting a box (B1) in this way has no effect on the
>   box (B2) that follows: B2 is given a position as if B1 were not offset
>   and B2 is not re-positioned after B1's offset is applied.

Instead, you can use margins:

```css
margin-left: 40px;
```

```css
#shrinkwrapper {
  float: left; /* Shrink-to-fit width */
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
#inner {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="shrinkwrapper">
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, the margin suggestion is really helpful.